# Слайдер в два уровня на CSS

Tags: html, css, slider

Подскажите, как можно на CSS реализовать следующую задачу. Необходимо сделать слайдер с встроенным в него подслайдером. 
Например: У нас есть машина ford. Мы можем выбрать для нее цвет: Синий, черный, белый. Предположим, что мы нажали на белый цвет. Рядом с фото, с низу или с боку - это не важно, появляется две строки "дизель", "бензин". По умолчанию стоит бензин. Рядом с типом ДВС указана стоимость. Допустим 100 руб. Если жмякнуть на дизель, то цена должна измениться, допустим на 95 руб.

В своих поисках, я наткнулся на статью на хабре, которую и взял за основу (http://habrahabr.ru/post/252075/). Слайдер на ее основе получился, а вот сделать выбор Дизель/бензин нет.
Если у кого-нибудь есть идеи по реализации, буду страшно благодарен.

Comment: В каждом слайде свой набор полей (дизель/бензин), или он один на все слайды? Зависит ли цена от от цвета, или только от второго набора полей (дизель/бензин)?

Comment: Да, для каждого цвета свой отдельный набор полей (дизель/бензин). Т.е. машины различаются по цвету (от этого зависит цена и по типу двигателя, опять же цена другая).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея таких слайдеров примерно следующая:

Html:

- Делаем радиобаттон (выше по коду)
- Делаем слайды (обычно они оборачиваются общим тегом)
- Делаем label'ы для радиобаттонов (label for - через id)

CSS:
- все слайды скрываем (более продвинутая техника - ставим в линию и делаем `transform: translateX` в зависимости от выбранного слайда)

- делаем так, чтобы радиобаттонов не было видно (`display: none` не подойдет - мы не сможем с ними работать, поэтому `position: absolute, visibility: hidden`)
- в зависимости от выбора радиобаттона (псевдокласс `checked`) показываем нужный слайд (через ~ - выбор соседнего элемента)

  input:nth-child(1):checked ~ .slides > .item:nth-child(1) { display: block; }

Далее, чтобы реализовать вложенный слайдер - вкладываем такую же (или аналогичную) конструкцию внутрь слайда.

Не забываем:

- поменять `id` и `name` у `<input type="radio">`
- атрибут `for` у `<label>`

[Подробная реализация примера на codepen](http://codepen.io/artbataev/pen/epBBzM)

P.S.: Штука получается довольно громоздкая. В качестве тренировки мозгов - хорошо, для использования в реальной жизни сомнительна - как правило, слайды хотят листать и на мобильных устройствах, таскать мышью и делать прочие вещи, которые на css ну никак не реализуемы.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Ваш вариант превосходно работает. К тому же в сочетании с bootstrap он еще и адаптивен. Прекрасно!

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен калькулятор с ползунками (слайдерами), на одном CSS это не сделать.

Comment: Нашел реализацию похожей штуки вот тут:
http://istore.of.by/
Калькулятор не нужен, необходимо просто отображать заранее прописанные значения. Посмотрите, там где можно выбирать цвет телефона и цену под ним.

Comment: Да это и есть Muse виджет - калькулятор, он сделан не на одном CSS.

Comment: Вероятно да, но тем не менее, есть варианты реализации 2-х уровненных слайдеров на js+css.